# Transaction not showing in Monero GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-data, linux

I recently transferred my funds from localmonero to the Monero GUI using a secondary address. I updated my GUI to version 17.1.1 before doing so. I am using the latest version of Tails OS. However, I am not seeing my transaction at all under transaction history. Monero gave me a transaction ID and said it has gone through but I am still not showing even the proof of transaction in the GUI. I've used different nodes, as well as refreshing the wallet, and still nothing is showing. Can someone please assist me with this?

Comment: Can you first verify the transaction? https://monero.stackexchange.com/revisions/6138/1

Comment: plz resync all block or restore your wallet on a new wallet